# Outline of corresponding pixels

Tags: matlab

What I am doing is a pixel-based tree detection with the build-in MATLAB funktion imregionalmax. After a few steps, i get a matrix which contains values from 1 to n, based on how many trees were detected. Each tree is represented through a unique number (see image below). Pixels that don't belong to a tree are represented through NaN.

[image: Tree matrix]

The result should look like this:

[image: Result]

The closest I have been getting to the result above is by using the contour function, although it doesn't quite do the job, as it draws the outline through the middle of the pixels rather than on the outside.

Edit: I have a matrix with height values (same size as the above) and the outline is supposed to be only an overlay. Also, i want this outline to really be on the pixels' edges.

Comment: You added an image of data (useless information, in general), but also did not mention why that data is not the one below. Are you just plainly looking for `imagesc` ?

Comment: I hope i could clarify this in my edit! imagesc does not yield satisfying results, as it fills the pixel as a whole, but I only want the outline to be drawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to have a positive value whenever there is a change in your ROI matrix.
Seems to me you are looking for `gradient`

Maybe try this:

```
[FX,FY]=gradient(ROI_Matrix);
res = FX~=0 | FY~=0; %so if there is a change in the x-direction or in the y-direction the result for that pixel is 1.

image(res)
```

[edit]

You want to draw lines, not color pixels. So let's draw lines

```
imagesc(ROI_Matrix);
[FX,FY]=gradient(ROI_Matrix);
FX = FX~=0;FY = FY~=0;
hold on;
%change in x, horizontal line
for i = 1:size(FX,2)
    for j = 1:size(FX,1)
        if FX(i,j)
            plot([i,i],[j,j+1],'k-');
        end
    end
end
%change in y, verticle line
for i = 1:size(FY,2)
    for j = 1:size(FY,1)
        if FY(i,j)
            plot([i,i+1],[j,j],'k-');
        end
    end
end
hold off;
```

Comment: This is close to what I want, but the pixels are filled as a whole and I only want the outline to be drawn.

Comment: So you want to draw lines between the pixels that differ. Maybe something with hold on and then draw for each pixel that is 1?

Comment: Thank you so much! Need to adjust it just a little bit, but this was exactly what i wanted!